# Unable to decode the fetch API request, which contains % in it

Tags: javascript, fetch, decode

I am sending a request through fetch API in react application.
The fetch url contains the name argument, I should be able to create an account for the username which contains % in it. But when i tried to pass this url, i am getting the error message as unable to decode.

- Note : This is http request
- Format URL : http://localhost/users/api/service/username=test12%,cn=Administrators,cn=test administration,o=nmc

The space between test and administrator converts to %20 as expected.
But the % is not allowing me to pass this request.

```
let constructed_URL = 'http://localhost/users/api/service/username=test12%,cn=Administrators,cn=test administration';
fetch(constructed_URL, {
  method: "get",
  headers: urlParameter
})
```

I expect the browser to decode %, and pass this request.

Comment: You can use the function's like encodeURI(uri) and decodeURI(encoded_uri), while requesting.!
Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: @Joshua: Welcome to SO! Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ? We appreciate your input, but please make sure that your answer is not looking hastily written.

Comment: Thanks @B--rian... I will try to quote my question in better way hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

fetch or console.error or Chrome somewhere automagically applies decodeURI (or -Component) if it thinks it was doubly encoded.
It doesn't behave that way if the URL is encoded thrice.

I wanted to use URIencoded file names in my file system directly. It simply is impossible to `fetch` these files at the moment.

Comment: Could someone look for the reason for this implicit behavior, please? Personally I'd consider this a bug but it seems to do that by design. It is impossible to debug without reading the sourcecode of the browser engine.